# difference between addresses of struct members as compile time constant

Tags: c++, struct, memory-address, compile-time

```
struct A {
    int a;
    .
    .
    .
    int b;
} obj;
```

`const ptrdiff_t diff = &obj->b - &obj->a;`

Will `diff` always contain a constant which doesn't change even when the program is run several times?

Will `diff` always be positive?

Is there a way to obtain that difference during compile-time? (other than manual counting)

Comment: Yes, yes, and the compiler will probably optimize it like that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you use offsetof() on a struct?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7180290/how-do-you-use-offsetof-on-a-struct)

Comment: C or C++ ? In what actuel language you are coding please don't tag question with C and C++ for no reason. C is not C++ is not C.

Comment: I was coding in C++ but I thought this would be relevant for both.

Comment: @Yashas answer could be relevant for both, question should not expect that the answer will be the same for two languages. If you want, made two question one with C and one with C++ but not both that will create a too broad question.

Comment: [This related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47616508/what-is-the-rationale-for-limitations-on-pointer-arithmetic-or-comparison) may be helpful.

Answer (score 5):

The behaviour of

```
const ptrdiff_t diff = &obj->b - &obj->a;
```

is *undefined*. You can only subtract two pointers if they point to elements in the same array, or one past the end of that array. For this purpose, a scalar is considered as an array of length 1.

It surprises me that this is a little known rule in C++, and C for that matter.

Although I've never come across a compiler that doesn't give you a "sensible" result, **don't** code like this, as you're not writing portable C++. With compiler optimisation techniques becoming more and more aggressive, you can fully expect code based on this to break in the future.

Comment: Is this UB: `if(size == (&obj->b - &obj->a))` where `size` is of type `int`?

Comment: Yup. A truck load of UB.

Comment: Would taking the difference of `offsetof`s of two members give the address difference between the two quantities? (I think it should but I've got too scared now)

Comment: @Yashas That will help if you post a question about your real problem and not what you think you need to do. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: My real problem is I need to pass an offset from a middle of a struct to another member of the struct to a function which is written in assembly.