# Is it undefined behavior to `reinterpret_cast` a `T*` to `T(*)[N]`?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, reinterpret-cast, strict-aliasing, c++17

Consider the following scenario:

```
std::array<int, 8> a;
auto p = reinterpret_cast<int(*)[8]>(a.data());
(*p)[0] = 42;
```

Is this *undefined behavior*? I think it is.

- `a.data()` returns a `int*`, which is not the same as `int(*)[8]`
- The [type aliasing rules](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast#Type_aliasing) on *cppreference* seem to suggest that the `reinterpret_cast` is not valid
- As a programmer, I know that the memory location pointed by `a.data()` is an array of `8` `int` objects

Is there any rule I am missing that makes this `reinterpret_cast` valid?

Comment: `std::array` is required to be a contiguous container. Thus, the question boils down to whether an `int * p` such that `[p; p+N)` is known to be a valid pointer range can be casted to `int[N]`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47924103/pointer-interconvertibility-vs-having-the-same-address

Comment: Misleading title. It's never UB to do a pointer cast. The potential problem would be accessing memory via dereferencing the result of the cast

Answer (score 15, accepted):

An array object and its first element are not pointer-interconvertible<sup>*</sup>, so the result of the `reinterpret_cast` is a pointer of type "pointer to array of 8 `int`" whose value is "pointer to `a[0]`"<sup>1</sup>.In other words, despite the type, it does not actually point to any array object.

The code then applies the array-to-pointer conversion to the lvalue that resulted from dereferencing such a pointer (as a part of the indexing expression `(*p)[0]`)<sup>2</sup>. That conversion's behavior is only specified when the lvalue actually refers to an array object<sup>3</sup>. Since the lvalue in this case does not, the behavior is undefined by omission<sup>4</sup>.

---

<sub><sup>*</sup>If the question is "why is an array object and its first element not pointer-interconvertible?", it has already been asked: [Pointer interconvertibility vs having the same address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47924103/pointer-interconvertibility-vs-having-the-same-address/47934218#47934218).</sub>

<sub><sup>1</sup>See [[expr.reinterpret.cast]/7](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/expr.reinterpret.cast#7), [[conv.ptr]/2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/conv.ptr#2), [[expr.static.cast]/13](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/expr.static.cast#13) and [[basic.compound]/4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/basic.compound#4).</sub>

<sub><sup>2</sup>See [[basic.lval]/6](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/basic.lval#6), [[expr.sub]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/expr.sub) and [[expr.add]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/expr.add).</sub>

<sub><sup>3</sup>[[conv.array]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/conv.array): "The result is a pointer to the first element of **the array**."</sub>

<sub><sup>4</sup>[[defns.undefined]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/defns.undefined): undefined behavior is "behavior for which this document imposes no requirements", including "when this document omits any explicit definition of behavior".</sub>

Comment: Are you saying that `std::array<int, 8>` doesn't contain any `int[8]` subobject, or are you saying the pointer doesn't point to that subobject? In either case, I think that would mean that `a.data() + 3` is also invalid, and we know that's supposed to be valid.

Comment: @hvd I'm saying that the pointer points to a subobject of that `int[8]` subobject; i.e., it's still pointing to an element of the array, not the array itself. You cannot obtain a pointer to the array from a pointer to an element with `reinterpret_cast`.

Comment: Okay, when I get back on my computer I'll check to see if I can find anything to counter that, and if not, delete my answer. Meanwhile, your logic would suggest that still, `std::launder` is enough to make it valid. Do you agree?

Comment: @hvd Only if you meet the no-extra-reachability requirement, which will depend on the array at issue.

Comment: In the OP's case, that should not be an issue, as far as I can tell. Every byte of the `int[8]` subobject was already accessible through `data()`.

Comment: @hvd The issue is whether you can access beyond that subobject with the resulting pointer. E.g., if `std::array<int, 8>` is something like `struct {int e[8]; char dummy;};` then a pointer to that `int[8]` is pointer-interconvertible with a pointer to the entire struct and so can reach `dummy`, which makes the `launder` undefined.

Comment: Following this line of thought, is it impossible to violate strict aliasing rules with reinterpret cast except with unions?

Comment: How can you though, when the pointer is unchanged by the cast unless there is interconvertibility?

Comment: @PasserBy `int i; *reinterpret_cast<float*>(&i) = 1;` attempts to modify `i` through an lvalue of type `float` that refers to `i`.

Comment: That `char dummy;` would pretty much require malice on the implementer's part, but true, the standard doesn't seem to prohibit it...

Answer (score 7):

Yes the behaviour is undefined.

`int*` (the return type of `a.data()`) is a different type from `int(*)[8]`, so you are breaking strict aliasing rules.

Naturally though (and this is more for the benefit of future readers),

```
int* p = a.data();
```

is perfectly valid, as is the ensuing expression `p + n` where the integral type `n` is between 0 and 8 inclusive.

Comment: I am casting the `.data()` though, not the array itself.

Comment: @VittorioRomeo: Oops. Corrected, the answer still holds though.

Comment: in 99.9999% of the cases I see where this might be useful. I would suggest using a [`gsl::span`](https://github.com/Microsoft/GSL) to solve the problem instead

Comment: I think this answer still is misleading or has a typo: *"`int*` is a completely different type from `std::array<int, N>*`" - I am not casting to `std::array<int, N>*`, but to `int(*)[8]` instead.

Comment: @VittorioRomeo: One more edit - I'm inclined to tin this.

Comment: I don't think it's a strict aliasing violation to use lvalue of type `int` to access an object of type `int` (which happens to be a member of an array)