# Treat plain old data array as std::array

Tags: c++, memory-management, stdarray

We have a large code base mainly written in `C`. We do a lot of numerical linear algebra.

In `C` we use `double*`, with length 3 to model a 3d vector.

In `C++` we use `std:array<double,3>` to model a 3d vector.

We have a small template library to overload a lot of operators, such as

```
template <class T, size_t N>
std::array<T, N> operator+(const std::array<T, N> &array1, const std::array<T, N> &array2) {
    std::array<T, N> a;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        a[i] = array1[i] + array2[i];
    }
    return a;
}
```

The problem comes, when we need to go from `C` to `C++` (the other way around is no problem, since we can use the .data() method to access the aligned memory). I do not like to make a copy of each c-like 3d vector, because this would be numerically expensive.

Can I treat a pod array as a std::array or is there a way of initializing an std::array in a way that no new memory is allocated, but the memory from the pod array is used?

I am thinking about using `gsl::span` from the [guideline support library](https://github.com/Microsoft/GSL), but I wonder if there is a better solution.

Comment: Is the C variant an array (`double[3]`) or dynamically allocated (`malloc(3*sizeof(double)`)?  You might want to take a look at [`array_view`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh305260.aspx) in the first case.

Answer (score -2):

You can simply cast:

```
double* c_array; // assign to whatever you like, length 3 or more
auto cpp_array = reinterpret_cast<std:array<double,3>*>(c_array);
```

This works because `std::array` is definitely nothing more than a struct containing a single C array.

Comment: I agree that this will work with every sensible implementation of the standard library, but there is nothing in the standard that guarantees it, right? Some implementation of `std::array` could perhaps add some additional debugging fields before the actual array...

Comment: I suspect it's Undefined Behavior. Yes, a `std::array<T,N>` **contains** a `T[N]`. That doesn't mean it _is_ a `T[N]`. And accessing an object via an expresion of incompatible type is UB.

Comment: [No, it is not safe even if `std::array` is nothing more than a struct containing a single C array.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48444004/is-it-undefined-behavior-to-reinterpret-cast-a-t-to-tn)

Comment: @michalsrb: No, std::array cannot contain additional debugging fields.   Not only is there nothing sensible to debug by doing so, but the widespread use of std::array in a way that demands it is a simple array internally would never allow such an implementation to succeed (meaning, have users).

Comment: @JohnZwinck: I can imagine things you could debug on `std::array`. For example a debug version of standard library could add a canary field before and after the array contained in `std::array` and test them in every method to detect out-of-bounds writes. That is plausible thing to do. It wouldn't break valid programs, but will break programs with this `reinterpret_cast`.

Comment: @michalsrb: It will break "valid" programs because people use std::array as a member of network messages and other things.  In practice what you are proposing is completing implausible because of how people use arrays (C and C++ ones).