# Treating 2D array as 1D array

Tags: c++, arrays

Let's say we have a 2D `int` array:

```
int a[3][4] = { { 1,3,2,4 }, { 2,1,5,3 }, { 0,8,2,3 } };
```

Is it legal and valid to take its address and reinterpret it as a pointer to 1D array of `int`s? Basically:

```
int *p = reinterpret_cast<int *>(&a);
```

So that I can do things like (roughly):

```
template<typename T, size_t X, size_t Y>
void sort2(T(&arr)[X][Y])
{
    T *p = reinterpret_cast<T *>(&arr);
    std::sort(p, p + X*Y);
}
```

DEMO: https://ideone.com/tlm190

To my knowledge, the standard guarantees that alignment of 2D array would be contiguous in memory, and although `p + X*Y` technically is out of range is never accessed so should not lead to Undefined Behaviour either.

Can I absolutely treat 2D arrays as 1D arrays when needed?

Comment: There are 2 schools of thought... some say it is legal and some say it isn't. Has been argued about in C and C++ for 30 years with no resolution

Comment: @M.M Thank you! I thought I was going crazy, hence the question :)

Comment: Not sure if it is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48444004/is-it-undefined-behavior-to-reinterpret-cast-a-t-to-tn. They are essentially the same.

Comment: @xskxzr Related yes, but not quite a duplicate

Comment: Anyway, [T.C.'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48446084/5376789) also applies to this question.

Comment: @xskxzr Thanks for the links, I think I get the idea now, and it is not what I expected

Comment: How about a simply `int *p = a[0];`?

Answer (score 4):

Thank you all for replying and commenting, but I think the correct answer is - as it stands the code exhibits technical UB, though correctable. I have looked through some of those questions [[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48444004/is-it-undefined-behavior-to-reinterpret-cast-a-t-to-tn), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48444004/is-it-undefined-behavior-to-reinterpret-cast-a-t-to-tn/48446084#48446084)] @xskxzr linked and it led me to [this quote from the standard](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.compound):

> If two objects are pointer-interconvertible, then they have the same
>   address, and it is possible to obtain a pointer to one from a pointer
>   to the other via a *reinterpret_­cast*. [ *Note*: **An array object and its
>   first element are not pointer-interconvertible, even though they have
>   the same address**. — *end note* ]

Then on [`reinterpret_cast` page](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast#Notes) there is the following note with an example:

> Assuming that alignment requirements are met, a *reinterpret_cast* does
>   not change the value of a pointer outside of a few limited cases
>   dealing with *pointer-interconvertible* objects:

```
int arr[2];
int* p5 = reinterpret_cast<int*>(&arr); // value of p5 is unchanged by reinterpret_cast and
                                        // is "pointer to arr"
```

Even though this [compiles without warning and runs](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=d6d827d53a8ae5a5), this is technically a UB because `p5` is technically still a pointer to `arr` and not to `arr[0]`. So basically the use of `reinterpret_cast` the way I used it leads to UB. Taking the above into account, if I were to create `int *` directly to the 1st `int` (and this is ok according to the answer by @codekaizer), then this should be valid, right?:

```
template<typename T, size_t X, size_t Y>
void sort2(T(&arr)[X][Y])
{
    T *p = &arr[0][0]; // or T *p = arr[0];
    std::sort(p, p + X * Y);
}
```

But it probably is UB as well since the pointer `p` is pointing to the first `T` of the first array of `T`s which has `Y` elements. `p + X*Y` therefore will be pointing out of range of this 1st array of `T`s, hence UB (thanks again to  @xskxzr for the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7269099/may-i-treat-a-2d-array-as-a-contiguous-1d-array/50795564#50795564) and comment).

> If the expression P points to element x[i] of an array object x with n
>   elements, the expressions P + J and J + P (where J has the value j)
>   point to the (possibly-hypothetical) element x[i+j] if 0≤i+j≤n;
>   otherwise, the behavior is undefined.

So here is my final attempt before I give up:

```
template<typename T, size_t X, size_t Y>
void sort2(T(&arr)[X][Y])
{
    T(&a)[X * Y] = reinterpret_cast<T(&)[X * Y]>(arr);
    std::sort(a, a + X * Y);
}
```

Here `T arr[X][Y]` is first converted to `T a[X*Y]` with, again, `reinterpret_cast`, which I think is now valid. The reinterpreted array `a` happily decays to a pointer to 1st element of array `a[X*Y]` (`a + X * Y` is also within the range) and gets converted to an iterator in `std::sort`.

**TL;DR version**

Behaviour in the OP is Undefined because of improper use of `reinterpret_cast`. The correct way to convert 2D array to 1D array would be:

```
//-- T arr2d[X][Y]
T(&arr1d)[X*Y] = reinterpret_cast<T(&)[X*Y]>(arr2d);
```

> An lvalue expression of type T1 can be converted to reference to
>   another type T2. The result is an lvalue or xvalue referring to the
>   same object as the original lvalue, but with a different type. No
>   temporary is created, no copy is made, no constructors or conversion
>   functions are called. The resulting reference can only be accessed
>   safely if allowed by the type aliasing rules

[Aliasing rules](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast):

> Whenever an attempt is made to read or modify the stored value of an
>   object of type DynamicType through a glvalue of type AliasedType, the
>   behavior is undefined unless one of the following is true:
>
> - AliasedType and DynamicType are similar.

[Type similarity](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast):

> Informally, two types are similar if, ignoring top-level
>   cv-qualification
>
> - they are both arrays of the same size or both arrays of unknown    bound, and the array element types are similar.

[Array element type](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.array):

> In a declaration `T` `D` where `D` has the form
>
> `D1 [ constant-expression opt ] attribute-specifier-seq opt`
>
> and the type of the identifier in the declaration `T` `D1` is
>   “*derived-declarator-type-list* `T`”,  then the type of the identifier of `D` is an array type; if the type of the identifier of `D` contains the auto *type-specifier*, the program is ill-formed. `T` is called the array *element type*;

Comment: The solution depends on the fact that a 2D array can be treated as a 1D array. You can see [my post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50795564/5376789) for details.

Comment: @xskxzr Thanks again for the link, I have adjusted my answer

Comment: The 1D array `a` refer to does not exist in reality, so array-to-pointer conversion results in undefined behavior. [T.C.'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48446084/5376789) also applies here.

Comment: @xskxzr I created `a` by telling compiler to treat the data as if it was a single array of `T`s. `a` is an array and `sizeof(a)` returns correct size, so compiler knows. I don’t see the problem here or how it can fail to decay into pointer.

Comment: You cannot treat 2D array as 1D array though they have the same memory location. You can read the [reinterpret_cast page](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast) of cppreference: "An lvalue expression of type T1 can be converted to reference to another type T2. The result is an lvalue or xvalue referring to the same object as the original lvalue, but with a different type. No temporary is created, no copy is made, no constructors or conversion functions are called. **The resulting reference can only be accessed safely if allowed by the type aliasing rules (see below)**".

Comment: @xskxzr I don’t see any breaking of aliasing rules here, do you?

Comment: I see your edit. `T[X*Y]` and `T[X][Y]` are not similar. `T[X*Y]` has length `X*Y` while `T[X][Y]` has length `X`, and the element type of `T[X*Y]` is `T` while the element type of `T[X][Y]` is `T[Y]`.

Comment: @xskxzr The size is the same and the similar element is T, I think you are misinterpreting documentation (or I do :))

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172977/discussion-between-xskxzr-and-killzone-kid).

Answer (score 2):

From http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/arrays/

```
int jimmy [3][5];   // is equivalent to
int jimmy [15];     // (3 * 5 = 15)
```

when creating an array ( of any dimension ) the array memory is a fixed block of memory in `size = sizeof(type) * dim0 * dim1 * ....;`

So to your question, yes you can recast the array safely into one dimensional array.

Comment: It's worth noting that this won't work with dynamically created arrays.

Comment: It's is "equivalent" but you can't cast `T[X][Y]` to `T[X*Y]`. One is of type `int**` the other `int*`

Comment: @Vivick Actually one is of type `int(*)[15]` and another one is of type `int(*)[3][5]`.

Comment: imho `[3][5]` being the same as `[15]` doesnt automatically mean that you can safely cast between them, they are still of different type

Answer (score 1):

**A 2D array cannot be treated as a 1D array**

As noted by @KillzoneKid, the address of an array is not pointer interconvertable with that of the first element even though they share the same address value.

`constexpr` provides a convenient way to evaluate UB. Compilers are required to detect UB when `constexpr`s are evaluated. Thus a simple test can be made. This function, when evaluated during compile time will detect accessing values beyond an array's range.

```
// sum "n" sequential ints
constexpr int sum(const int* pi, int n) {
    int sum = 0;
    while (n-- > 0)
        sum += *pi++;
    return sum;
};
```

When this is called at runtime with a pointer to the first element of a 1D or 2D array it will sum the elements but is UB if "n" goes beyond the boundary of the array. For a 2D array, this would be the extent of the lowest dimension. Not the size of the whole array.

Examining different instances of a pointer to an int we can see UB occurs once we try to access a value beyond the array dimension.

```
int main()
{
    constexpr int i0{1};
    constexpr int i1[2]{ 1,2 };
    constexpr int i2[2][2] = { { 1,2}, {3,4} };

    constexpr int sum0 = sum(&i0, 1);       // fails for n>1
    constexpr int sum1 = sum(&i1[0], 2);    // fails for n>2
    constexpr int sum2 = sum(&i2[0][0], 2); // fails for n>2
    const int sum3 = sum(&i2[0][0], 4);     // runtime calc, UB. fails if constexpr

    return sum0 + sum1 + sum2 + sum3;       // 17
}
```

For accesses beyond existing data, such as in sum0 and sum1, UB is clear. But sum2 points to existing data for n=[0:3) yet constexpr evaluation shows it to be UB for n=4.

I was somewhat surprised to learn this. Every compiler I've ever used worked as expected when doing things like scaling all the coefficients of a matrix by a fixed amount. But I can see rationales based on optimization assumptions that portions of a matrix won't change from the result of a function call on another part not in the same array sequence.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It is legal and valid.

As per [dcl.array](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.array#7):

> If E is an n-dimensional array of rank i×j×⋯×k , then E appearing in
>   an expression that is subject to the *array-to-pointer* conversion is
>   converted to a pointer to an (n−1)-dimensional array with rank  j×⋯×k.
>   If the `*` operator, either explicitly or implicitly as a result of
>   subscripting, is applied to this pointer, the result is the pointed-to
>   (n−1)-dimensional array, which itself is immediately converted into a
>   pointer.

Comment: Why is this paragraph related to the question?

Comment: So `int a[3][4]` can be converted to `int (*)[4]`. OP wants to go until `int*`...