# Wording of array-to-pointer conversion and undefined behaviour

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

According to [conv.array](https://eel.is/c++draft/conv.array), array-to-pointer conversion is defined like this (bold emphasis mine):

> An lvalue or rvalue of type “array of N T” or “array of unknown bound of T” can be converted to a prvalue of type “pointer to T”. The temporary materialization conversion ([conv.rval]) is applied. The result is a pointer to the first element of **the array**

This wording seems to assume that expression, subject to the conversion, refers to an array which is implicitly understood to be the one referred to by emphasized *"the array"*. However, this is not necessarily the case since it's legally possible, e.g., to have lvalue of type `T[N]` referring to object of type `T`:

```
int a[5];
auto pa = reinterpret_cast<int(*)[5]>(&a[0]);
```

Now, `*pa` is lvalue of type `int[5]`, but refers to `int` object (the first element of `a`) since during `reinterpret_cast` *pointer-value* was unchanged due to `int[5]` and `int` being not *pointer-interconvertible* types. Note that, on the other hand, `*std::launder(pa)` is an expression of type `int[5]` referring to `int[5]` object at the address represented by `pa` (i.e., `a`), so array-to-pointer conversion would apply to it in an obvious way if needed, e.g., by subscript operator. However, applying the conversion to `*pa` (which applies because expression type is appropriate) results in lack of obvious interpretation of what *"the array"* from above wording means in this case (and, thus, what resulting pointer points to). In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48446084/3162368) answer (to question about whether `T*` and `T(*)[N]` are pointer-interconvertible), where such situation arises, it's interpreted that behaviour is *undefined by omission*, however as explained above the quoted paragraph does apply and defines behaviour (*"The result is"* provided regardless of something like "if the expression refers to array", such condition is absent from wording), but meaning of *"the array"* is unclear.

So, is in this case

- behaviour indeed undefined per current wording contrary to my observations (if yes, why),
- defined in some non-obvious way (if yes, in which way),
- the wording is imprecise?

Comment: Just because something is UB doesn't mean it can't do what you expect. `reinterpret_cast<double*>(&a[0]);` compiles to but is equally as wrong. An array decays into a pointer to the first element but the reverse is not true.

Comment: Note `temporary materialization conversion` in the paragraph. The array and pointer aren't identical or equivalent, one gets converted into the other. It only happens that on nearly all systems the conversion is a NOP as is the static_cast.

Comment: The answer by T.C. on the question you linked, appears to cover everything you asked?  (I.e. undefined by omission)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The paragraph is just in general imprecise, in my opinion. It doesn't say what "*the array*" refers to at all. No array has been introduced before, only array types.

I guess it should probably state explicitly that it refers to the array object result of the glvalue, after temporary materialization if applicable.

Then I think it should also have a requirement that the type of that result object be *similar* to that of the original expression type. That way the result object will always be an array object and it can't have a "wrong" type in the same sense as for pointer arithmetic which already applies in a manual `&pa[0]` "decay". (see [[expr.add]/6](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.add#6))

But that is my own interpretation of what seems a reasonable interpretation/improvement. I don't think the current wording makes that clear.

---

This is not the only part of the standard with imprecise wording in regard to lvalue type mismatches like this. See for example [CWG 2535](https://github.com/cplusplus/CWG/issues/5) for a similar situation with member access, where a similar resolution is suggested.