# Can std::launder be used to convert an object pointer to its enclosing array pointer?

Tags: c++, c++17, language-lawyer, stdlaunder

The current draft standard (and presumably C++17) say in [[basic.compound/4]](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.compound#4):

> [ Note: An array object and its first element are not pointer-interconvertible, even though they have the same address. — end note ]

So a pointer to an object cannot be `reinterpret_cast`'d to get its enclosing array pointer.

Now, there is `std::launder`, [[ptr.launder/1]](http://eel.is/c++draft/ptr.launder#1):

> `template<class T> [[nodiscard]] constexpr T* launder(T* p) noexcept`;
>
> Requires: `p` represents the address A of a byte in memory. An object X that is within its lifetime and whose type is similar to T is located at the address A. All bytes of storage that would be reachable through the result are reachable through `p` (see below).

And the definion of *reachable* is in [[ptr.launder/3]](http://eel.is/c++draft/ptr.launder#3):

> Remarks: An invocation of this function may be used in a core constant expression whenever the value of its argument may be used in a core constant expression. A byte of storage is reachable through a pointer value that points to an object Y if it is within the storage occupied by Y, an object that is pointer-interconvertible with Y, or the **immediately-enclosing array object if Y is an array element**. The program is ill-formed if T is a function type or cv void.

Now, at first sight, it seems that `std::launder` is can be used to do the aforementioned conversion, because of the part I've put emphasis.

But. If `p` points to an object of an array, the bytes of the array is *reachable* according to this definition (even though `p` is not pointer-interconvertible to array-pointer), just like the result of the launder. So, it seems that the definition doesn't say anything about this issue.

So, can `std::launder` be used to convert an object pointer to its enclosing array pointer?

Comment: "Reachable" here is a terminology. The latter part of the "remarks:" paragraph is only an interpretation/definition of the terminology "reachable" in the "requires:" paragraph.

Comment: In case of array, "reachable" refers to simple pointer arithmetic like `p + 1`. You can reach any element from any other element. Pointer interconvertibility though refers to conversion to pointer *to the entire array*, like `int (*) [10]`, which is a completely different story. You don't need this interconvertibility to reach other elements.

Comment: @AnT: thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This depends on whether the enclosing array object is a complete object, and if not, whether you can validly access more bytes through a pointer to that enclosing array object (e.g., because it's an array element itself, or pointer-interconvertible with a larger object, or pointer-interconvertible with an object that's an array element). The "reachable" requirement means that you cannot use `launder` to obtain a pointer that would allow you to access more bytes than the source pointer value allows, on pain of undefined behavior. This ensures that the possibility that some unknown code may call `launder` does not affect the compiler's escape analysis.

I suppose some examples could help. Each example below `reinterpret_cast`s a `int*` pointing to the first element of an array of 10 `int`s into a `int(*)[10]`. Since they are not pointer-interconvertible, the `reinterpret_cast` does not change the pointer value, and you get a `int(*)[10]` with the value of "pointer to the first element of (whatever the array is)". Each example then attempts to obtain a pointer to the entire array by calling `std::launder` on the cast pointer.

```
int x[10];
auto p = std::launder(reinterpret_cast<int(*)[10]>(&x[0]));
```

This is OK; you can access all elements of `x` through the source pointer, and the result of the `launder` doesn't allow you to access anything else.

```
int x2[2][10];
auto p2 = std::launder(reinterpret_cast<int(*)[10]>(&x2[0][0]));
```

This is undefined. You can only access elements of `x2[0]` through the source pointer, but the result (which would be a pointer to `x2[0]`) would have allowed you to access x2[1], which you can't through the source.

```
struct X { int a[10]; } x3, x4[2]; // assume no padding
auto p3 = std::launder(reinterpret_cast<int(*)[10]>(&x3.a[0])); // OK
```

This is OK. Again, you can't access through a pointer to `x3.a` any byte you can't access already.

```
auto p4 = std::launder(reinterpret_cast<int(*)[10]>(&x4[0].a[0]));
```

This is (intended to be) undefined. You would have been able to reach `x4[1]` from the result because `x4[0].a` is pointer-interconvertible with `x4[0]`, so a pointer to the former can be `reinterpret_cast` to yield a pointer to the latter, which then can be used for pointer arithmetic. See https://wg21.link/LWG2859.

```
struct Y { int a[10]; double y; } x5;
auto p3 = std::launder(reinterpret_cast<int(*)[10]>(&x5.a[0]));
```

And this is again undefined, because you would have been able to reach `x5.y` from the resulting pointer (by `reinterpret_cast` to a `Y*`) but the source pointer can't be used to access it.

Comment: So according to this reasoning, somehow the _source_ of the expression affects the semantics of `std::launder`? That sounds insane as a mental model, regardless how optimizers are implemented. Reminds me of the whole pointer provenance thing.

Comment: Perhaps `std::launder` is precisely for those situations where the "mental model" _is_ insane ;-)

Comment: The specification of `std::launder` says nothing at all about the argument of `reinterpret_cast`, or indeed about `reinterpret_cast`. It only states things about the argument and the result of `std::launder`. That is, in the cases you consider, about the *result* of `reinterpret_cast`.

Comment: @n.m. In all the examples above, the `reinterpret_cast` doesn't change the pointer value. It remains "pointer to the first element of (whatever the array is)".

Comment: Yes, but it is **not** "a pointer to the array as a whole", despite having the same value. You need `std::launder` to make it so. That's the entire point.

Comment: Right, and the point of the examples is to illustrate when you can and cannot launder.

Comment: The problem here is that you are trying to make a point based on the false premises/misread wording of the standard. The result of `std::launder(reinterpret_cast<int(*)[10]>(&x2[0][0]));` does not depend on what you are allowed to do with `&x2[0][0]`. It only depends on the type and the *value* of the argument of `std::launder`, which is the result of `reinterpret_cast`.

Comment: The *value* of the argument is "pointer to `x2[0][0]`"; the attempt is to launder it into "pointer to `x2[0]`", which is disallowed because the bytes comprising `x2[1]` is reachable from the latter value but not former. I'm not understanding what you are complaining about.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176911/discussion-between-n-m-and-t-c).

Comment: Thanks for the answer T.C., great explanation!

Answer (score 2):

Remark: any non schizophrenic compiler will probably gladly accept that, as it would accept a C-style cast or a re-interpret cast, so just try and see is not an option.

But IMHO, the answer to your question is no. The emphasized *immediately-enclosing array object if Y is an array element* lies in a *Remark* paragraph, not in the *Requires* one. That means that provided the requires section is respected, the remarks one also applies. As an array and its element type are not similar types, the requirement is not satisfied and `std::launder` cannot be used.

What follows is more of a general (philosophycal?) interpretation. At the time of K&R C (in the 70's), C was intended to be able to replace assembly language. For that reason the rule was: the compiler must obey the programmer provided the source code can be translated. So no strict aliasing rule and a pointer was no more that an address with additional arithmetics rules. This strongly changed in C99 and C++03 (not speaking of C++11 +). Programmers are now supposed to use C++ as a high level language. That means that a pointer is just an object that allows to access another object of a given type, and an array and its element type are totally different types. Memory addresses are now little more than implementation details. So trying to convert a pointer to an array to a pointer to its first element is then against the philosophy of the language and could bite the programmer in a later version of the compiler. Of course real life compiler still accept it for compatibility reasons, but we should not even try to use it in modern programs.

Comment: An array is located at the same address as its first element, and the array type is definitely similar to itself, so the requires section does apply.

Comment: @n.m.: just to clarify: do you mean, that the answer is "Yes"?

Comment: Yes I think so. Disclaimer: this was stated in an answer (deleted by a moderator) to [this question of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47924103/pointer-interconvertibility-vs-having-the-same-address).

Comment: @n.m. : I've read the deleted answer you cite. I do not agree with it, but IMHO it is an answer an not a comment. So I wonder whether it has not been wrongly deleted. Would you mind if I ask on meta about it?

Comment: @n.m.: I have just asked a [question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/371664/3545273) about that on meta...

Comment: @LanguageLawyer I tried to edit your post to make it an answer, but it changes it too much for a third person edit. If you agree with my edits, add a new edit to make clear that you accept that and ping me in a comment so that I can ask for the post to be undeleted.

Comment: @geza I'm no longer sure the answer is yes.