# How to interpret the reachability requirement of std::launder?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++17, stdlaunder

The `std::launder` function requires that every byte that would be reachable through the result is reachable through the argument. "Reachable" is defined as follows:

> A byte of storage is reachable through a pointer value that points to an object *Y* if it is within the storage occupied by *Y*, an object that is
>   pointer-interconvertible with *Y*, or the immediately-enclosing array object if *Y* is an array element.

According to [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51561687/481267) to another question, this restriction "... means that you cannot use `launder` to obtain a pointer that would allow you to access more bytes than the source pointer value allows, on pain of undefined behavior."

This makes sense for the examples given by T.C. but I don't understand how to interpret it in the case where the original object has been replaced by a new object, which is the original purpose contemplated for `std::launder`. The standard has the following example:

```
struct X { const int n; };
X *p = new X{3};
const int a = p->n;
new (p) X{5}; // p does not point to new object (6.8) because X::n is const
const int b = p->n; // undefined behavior
const int c = std::launder(p)->n; // OK
```

In this case, by the time `std::launder` is called, the object pointed to by `p`---the original `X` object---has already ceased to exist since the creation of a new object in the storage it occupied has implicitly ended its lifetime ([basic.life]/1.4). Therefore, it seems that there are no bytes reachable through `p` since `p` does not point to any object *Y*. This is obviously not the intended reading since it would make the call to `std::launder` undefined behaviour in the example.

1. Have I misunderstood the wording here, or is the wording defective?
2. What is the intended meaning, which would make the example valid?

Comment: "Points to an out-of-lifetime object" != "doesn't point to an object".

Comment: I think that key part is `within the storage occupied by Y`. So even if lifetime ended, storage is available, and a pointer can point to it (pointer value doesn't become invalid pointer value).

Comment: @T.C. If your answer is that objects are still considered to exist in storage after their lifetime has ended, you should post that as an answer. I can't figure out what stance the C++17 standard adopts on this---it seems to me that it may be inconsistent.

Comment: Don't forget that because ptr are trivial types, technically you can always use an "invalid" ptr if there is some object that address.

Answer (score 1):

Just going by the example, the relevant text is (Bold is mine):

> A byte of storage is reachable through **a pointer value that points to
>   an object Y** if it is within the storage occupied by Y

Due to the *placement new*, the pointer value now points to the "newly placed" object, and hence the reachability is of that.

I would say that is clear enough as it stands.