# How to interpret the precondition of std::launder?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, stdlaunder

```cpp
struct X { int n; };
const X *p = new const X{3};  // #1
new (const_cast<X*>(p)) const X{5};  // #2
const int c = std::launder(p)->n;
```

Assume that the object created at `#1` is named `obj1` while the object created at `#2` is named `obj2`. The precondition of `std::launder` is that

[ptr.launder] p2 [link](https://eel.is/c++draft/ptr.launder)

> p represents the address A of a byte in memory. An object X that is within its lifetime and whose type is similar to T is located at the address A. **All bytes of storage that would be reachable through the result are reachable through p (see below)**.
>
> A byte of storage b is reachable through a pointer value that points to an object Y if there is an object Z, pointer-interconvertible with Y, such that b is within the storage occupied by Z, or the immediately-enclosing array object if Z is an array element.

This rule is a bit obscure. Is the following interpretation a right read?

`obj2` will occupy the number of `sizeof(X)` bytes beginning with `A`. Consider `Y`(the object to which `std::launder(p)` points) and `Z`(namely, `obj2`) as the same object, they are pointer-interconvertible, and the `sizeof(X)` bytes occupied by `obj2` are all within `Z`, hence these bytes are all reachable through `std::launder(p)`. that is, "All bytes of storage that would be reachable through the result". Whether these bytes are reachable through `p`? With the assumption that `Y` (namely, the object to which `p` points) and `Z` are the same object `obj1`, which are also the array element of a hypothetical array, as per [basic.compound] p3

> an object of type T that is not an array element is considered to belong to an array with one element of type T.

Since these bytes beginning with `A` are all within the array of which `Z` is an element. Hence, we can say these bytes are all reachable through `p`?

Comment: Can you put what it is you are trying to conclude at the front of your interpretation?  Like, "I would like to say BLAH".  I think you are trying to say "`obj2`s bytes are reachable through `p`", but decoding your paragraph isn't easy.  Too much renaming of things and pronouns.  Every time you say "these", for example, I have to do a bunch of work to figure out exactly which "these" you are talking about.  I could assume, but you want to know if you are right, not if what I read your words as saying is right.

Comment: How [basic.compound]/3 is related? It says «For purposes of pointer arithmetic ([expr.add]) and comparison ([expr.rel], [expr.eq])», not «For any purposes»

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51552713/can-stdlaunder-be-used-to-convert-an-object-pointer-to-its-enclosing-array-poi

Comment: @LanguageLawyer How do you interpret the definition of "reachable through"?

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont The above are all based on my opinion for how to interpret "reachable through" to make all bytes that are reachable through `std::launder(p)` can be reachable through `p`. Since the above comment points out that [basic.compound]/3 is irrelevant here. Obviously, my opinion is wrong since it's based on a false premise. Except that `obj1`(p points to) would be pointer-interconvertible with `obj2`, I cannot figure out why those bytes that are reachable through `std::launder(p)` can be reachable through `p`, according to the definition of `reachable through`.

Comment: @xmh0511 as described in http://eel.is/c++draft/ptr.launder#4.sentence-2

Comment: @LanguageLawyer Hmmm... I was not saying the pure definition of "reachable through". I just wondered how do you interpret the aforementioned example through the current definition of "reachable through".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[basic.compound]/3 is not relevant. It specifically says that it applies only for the purpose of pointer arithmetic and comparison. There doesn't actually exist an array for the object.

I think when you call `std::launder`, there are four objects at the relevant address: `obj1`, `obj1.n`, `obj2` and `obj2.n`.
`obj1` and `obj1.n` are pointer-interconvertible, as are `obj2` and `obj2.n`. Other combinations aside from identical pairs, are not pointer-interconvertible. There are no array objects and therefore *"or the immediately-enclosing array object if Z is an array element."* isn't relevant.

When considering reachability from `std::launder(p)`, which points to `obj2` thus only `obj2` and `obj2.n` need to be considered as `Z` in the quote. `obj2.n` occupies an (improper) subset of bytes of `obj2`, so it is not relevant. The bytes reachable are those in `obj2`. Except that I considered `obj2.n` specifically, this is a rephrasing of your considerations.

By exactly the same reasoning, the bytes reachable from `p` (pointing to `obj1`) are all those in `obj1`.

`obj1` and `obj2` have the same size and therefore occupy exactly the same bytes. Therefore `std::launder(p)` would not make any bytes reachable that aren't reachable from `p`.

Comment: *`obj1` and `obj2` have the same size and therefore occupy exactly the same bytes. Therefore...* That's not what the definition of "reachable through" says, Isn't it? All bytes that are reachable through `std::launder(p)` is those within `obj2`, and `p` points to `obj1`, with this condition, except that `obj1` is pointer-interconvertible with `obj2`, I cannot figure out why those bytes that are reachable through `std::launder(p)` can be reachable through `p`.

Comment: @xmh0511 I don't think `obj1` and `obj2` are pointer-interconvertible. The _reachable through_ definition says that any single byte is _reachable_ if one of the Z objects occupies storage containing it. Suppose `X` has size `4`. There are exactly four bytes occupied by `obj1`, starting at address `&obj1`. `obj2` also occupies exactly four bytes starting at address `&obj2`, but the two addresses are the same and therefore these four bytes of storage are exactly the same.

Comment: So, you mean that the definition of *reachable through* only purposes to determine which bytes a single pointer to an object can be reachable? To determine whether these bytes in two irrelevant(disjoint) objects to which the two pointers point to can be reachable through by each other, it relies on whether these bytes themself have certain relationships(e.g., the two objects contain the same bytes)?

Comment: @xmh0511 The whole point of the requirement is to make sure that you can't use `std::launder` followed by `reinterpret_cast` and pointer arithmetic to access memory locations that you couldn't before, since that would impede compiler optimizations. I am not saying that the bytes occupied by the two objects have a relationship of being equal, I am saying that they are the same identical bytes. Bytes are the fundamental memory unit and objects are simply placed on top of them. https://eel.is/c++draft/basic#intro.memory-1

Comment: I didn't say they *have a relationship of being equal*. I said *it relies on whether these bytes themself have certain relationships(e.g., the two objects contain the **same bytes**)*, specifically, all bytes that `A` can reach have the same address as those bytes that `B` can reach, this should be the same as what you said *《they are the same identical bytes》*

Comment: @xmh0511 Then I think we agree and have the same interpretation.