# std::launder vs placement-new reachability condition

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, placement-new, stdlaunder

`std::launder` has a precondition that all bytes reachable from the would-be-returned pointer are reachable through the passed pointer.

My understanding is that this is meant to allow compiler optimizations, so that e.g.

```
struct A {
    int a[2];
    int b;
};

void f(int&);

int g() {
    A a{{0,0},2};
    f(a.a[0]);
    return a.b;
}
```

can be optimized to always return `2`. (see [Pointer interconvertibility vs having the same address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47924103/pointer-interconvertibility-vs-having-the-same-address) and [Can std::launder be used to convert an object pointer to its enclosing array pointer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51552713/can-stdlaunder-be-used-to-convert-an-object-pointer-to-its-enclosing-array-poi))

---

Does this mean the reachability precondition should also apply to placement-new? Otherwise is there anything preventing me from writing `f` as follows?:

```
void f(int& x) {
    new(&x) A{{0,0},0};
}
```

The address of `a.a[0]` is the same as that of `a` and the new `A` object is transparently replaceable with the old `A` object, so that `a.b` in `g` should now be `0`.

Comment: Yes, looks undefined. But I'm not sure if this optimization is applied in practice, probably not.

Comment: _Does this mean the reachability precondition should also apply to placement-new?_ This needs strawpool for voting. But I'd say yes.

Comment: @LanguageLawyer So right now there is no other rule forbidding it that I am overlooking?

Comment: @LanguageLawyer If it they are not transparently replaceable, I would assume that `return a.b;` in `g` is going to be UB for accessing the member outside the object's lifetime. It wouldn't affect the optimization.

Comment: @user17732522 ah, I didn't look above `f`

Comment: I've thought I was only privately thinking about it, but no: https://groups.google.com/a/isocpp.org/g/std-discussion/c/u5TafpMrNMU/m/ajkba852EQAJ