# Is it valid to perform pointer arithmetic with a newly created subobject of an array?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

Is the operation of rewriting the value of `object3` by the following source code valid in the current C++ standard?

```
#include <iostream>

void foreign_function(short* s);

int main() {
    alignas(8) char object1[16];

    short* p_object2 = new(object1 + 2) short(10);  // Create object2 of type short
    long* p_object3 = new(object1 + 8) long(100);   // Create object3 of type long

    foreign_function(p_object2);

    std::cout << *p_object3  << std::endl;
}

void foreign_function(short* s) {
    char* p_object4 = new(s) char();  // Create object4 of type char
    char* pointer5 = p_object4 + 6;   // (*) pointer arithmetic
    new(pointer5) long(1000);  // object3 is transparently replaceable by the new object ([basic.life] p8)
}
```

In particular, I am wondering if the pointer operation indicated by (*) is valid.

When `object2` is created, `object1` provides storage for `object2` according to the [intro.object] p3, and therefore lifetime of `object1` does not end.

https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/intro.object#3

https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/intro.object#4.2

https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/basic.memobj#basic.life-1.5

However, the lifetime of the second and third elements of `object1`, objects of type char, ends.
The same is true when creating `object3`.

Then, when `object4` of type char is created, the lifetime of `object2` ends.
In this case, `object4` becomes a subobject of `object1` according to [intro.object] p2.
The element of `object1` that once existed at the same address as `object4`, i.e., the second element of `object1`, has already reached the end of its lifetime, but according to [intro.object] p2 that should not be a problem.

https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/intro.object#2

It seems to me that `p_object4` can be used for pointer arithmetic according to [expr.add] p4.2.

https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/expr.add#4.2

However, [intro.object] p2 only specifies that `object4` is a subobject of `object1`.
Can `object4` really be properly treated as the second element of `object1`?

https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/dcl.array#6

Comment: What is a practical usage of such unreadable code? Just curiosity?

Comment: For example, I am thinking of an allocator that uses boundary tags.
If such operations are prohibited, it would be difficult to subtract an address from the pointer of the object given to deallocate to get the previous tag without UB.

PS: std::launder is required to access the previous tag after subtracting the address.

Comment: just looking at that line you marked with (*), yes it is valid, there is nothing wrong with adding to a char pointer

Comment: @hogeegoh: Not commenting on your actual question but allocators are often provided by the implementation, and that is allowed to violate all sorts of rules (under the assumption that an implementer knows enough to make their otherwise UB code result in the outcome demanded by the standard).

Comment: `new(pointer5) long(1000);` may cause alignment issues though.

Comment: I would hide all the machinery in a datatructure because you are going to need a lot of invariant checking including calculating offsets based on the sizeof() instead of using raw integers.

Comment: @SvenNilsson: pointer arithmetic is only allowed on array, `p_object4 ` is not. `foreign_function` would be UB for sure if `s` point on regular `short`. Question is, is `p_object4 ` an element of `object1` here. I think there is a need to `std::launder` to make it valid.

Comment: It seems that before C++14, the compiler was not allowed to optimize away memory allocations. As long as all those calls to "placement new" are actually performed, I don't see any UB.  Related thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31873616/is-the-compiler-allowed-to-optimize-out-heap-memory-allocations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However, [intro.object] p2 only specifies that `object4` is a subobject of `object1`. Can `object4` really be properly treated as the second element of `object1`?

First of all, `object4` must be an array element, because [intro.object]/2 specifies that subobjects are member subobjects, base class subobjects, or array elements. And since `object4` can only be an array element, which one is it? Well, according to [dcl.array]/6 the only elements of `object1` are numbered 0 through 15, and `object4` happens to occupy the storage allocated for the element with index 2, so how could it be anything else?

But I think there's something fishy about this code: it defeats the compiler's reachability analysis, whereby when a pointer to a `float` object is passed to `foreign_function`, the latter should only be able to use that pointer to affect bytes that are reachable from that `float` object. But if `object4` is truly an element of `object1`, then a pointer to `object4` certainly can be used to access any byte in `object1`. So it seems like the current wording needs to be amended to prevent this from happening somehow, but I'm not sure about the correct direction. I'll raise this issue with the Core Working Group.

Comment: For reference: I asked whether placement-`new` contradicts the reachability conditions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70807452/stdlaunder-vs-placement-new-reachability-condition) and @LanguageLaywer mentioned that he had brought this up before. In this question the method used to circumvent reachability is a bit different, but the simpler approach is also still inconsistent with `std::launder`.

Comment: Thank you very much! Your inquiry to CWG would be greatly appreciated. I, too, was concerned by the inconsistency in the reachability analysis and wondered if the code was in fact UB, and that is why I asked this question.

Comment: By the way, I also have a few questions about [dcl.array] p6.
Is it talking about subobjects that are "within their lifetime" or subobjects that are "regardless of their lifetime"?
If the former, then the "N subobjects" is inconsistent, since some subobjects end their lifetime when object2 or objest3 is created.
If the latter, then new subobjects would be added when object4 is created, which would read as a contradiction.

Comment: @hogeegoh It means "regardless of lifetime". If you end the lifetime of one of the array elements by reusing the storage, it's still there, but not within its lifetime. If you then reuse the storage again to recreate an object of the element type, the new object transparently replaces the one that used to be there.

Comment: @Brian Bi I think that "transparently replaceable" is a pointer, reference, and name convention, and that there is no particular change in the "replaced" object itself.
That is, the original second subobject of the object1, the char object whose lifetime has ended, remains a subobject of object1 even after being "transparently replaced" by object4?
In that case, there would be 17 subobjects of object1.
That being said, this is nitpicking and overall I agree with your opinion.